# Can I prevent being attacked?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I am wondering if I can prevent myself from being attacked on Clash of Clans. I am not willing to wait for the money and elixir to generate again. I have a town hall level 7 and I want to do my first upgrade for the dragon and I want to stop players from attacking me.

For example: If I had like 10,000 gold and 1,000,000 elixir and no shield I am likely to be attacked, because when I am attacking other players, I usually only attack those who have more than 180,000 of each kind.

Comment: @ardaozkal Not true at all. You will be disconnected for inactivity if you do not touch the screen constantly

Comment: Please don't add extra questions to your question.  If you have new ones, use the Ask Question button at the top.  To that end, I have rolled back your additional question edit.

Answer (score 1):

TL:DR you cannot stop people from attacking you, as that is part of the game mechanics as designed by supercell.

No, you cannot prevent people from attacking you indefinitely. you can try to stay online, but after 3 hours it will force you to take a break. you can buy shields with gems, but they will eventually run out, and there are cooldowns on how often you can buy a shield, so you cannot keep buying shields to prevent people from attacking you. and as of the recent update, while attacking with a shield does not destroy it like it used to, it will take time off of it.

Comment: After the break if you're on again for 15 minutes it'll require another break. Then 3 hours again.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot fully prevent attacks but you can make yourself less of a target by purposefully having low resources. If you have low resources then there is little to no reason to attack you.